# How should I show my app's icon on Facebook's friend list in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am new in handling apps that will be connecting with Facebook.

I want to let my user log in my app with Facebook account and be able to send something, for example, a gift to their Facebook friends.

I want to get the user's friends list and which is very easy by using FBFriendPickerViewController. However, I want to have an effect that if their Facebook friend(s) is/are also using my app, the app icon will be shown at the right hand side of the user table cell (Just like some Phone Contact lists will show if the contact has Whatsapp/ Google+)

I have been searching through sites but still find nothing about this.

So my question is, is there any "official" way (using Facebook SDK method) to show the icon?

Or I have been thinking of another approach is that, I first get the friend list and then saved it, with the information that whether the "friend" is using my app or not. Then I create a custom friend picker view and check the condition to enable/disable the visibility of the app icon.

I can get the information by using approached of using GraphAPI fields or using external database, for which are mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956639/replacement-for-old-getappusers-call-to-see-a-users-friends-who-use-my-app) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298172/need-help-getting-list-of-friends-using-the-same-application-in-facebook-using-j)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475155/how-to-find-facebook-friends-using-the-same-app) .....

Anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I end up with customizing my own table view... : )